# Vim Surround inserts extra space around the word

Tags: vim, surround

When I select the word and use the surround plugin with `S`:

```
foobar
```

It becomes

```
( foobar )
```

How do I remove the extra spaces, so that it becomes

```
(foobar)
```

What should I place in my settings?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

If you type <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>, it will be surrounded by spaces. However if you use the closing `)` instead <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> it will not be surrounded by spaces.

This applies of course to all bracket pair surroundings, `<> [] {} ()`, not merely to `()`, although the behavior of <kbd>S</kbd><kbd><</kbd> is such that it expects a tag enclosure so only <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>></kbd> is able to surround as `<>`.

Comment: Thank you... I can't believe how long I've put up with the extra whitespace without realising this!

Comment: What about surround elements where both opening and closing symbols are the same, eg quotes?

Comment: @npit As far as I know, quoting always surrounds without spaces.  I don't know if there is a way to change that, and have never had a need for it.

Comment: Now this is a good design choice. Maybe not the easiest to discover though.

Comment: I'm late to the game - but is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Similarly, for changing `[this]` to `(this)`, it's `cs[)`.

Answer (score 32):

When you use the surround plugin you can use:

`cs)` instead of `cs(` to surround without space :).